# What vendor can I use Vanquisher's Mark of Sanctification

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I picked up some transmorg tier 10 pieces it looks like during a mount run in ICC. Vanquisher's Mark of Sanctification - http://www.wowhead.com/item=52025/vanquishers-mark-of-sanctification#contained-in-object.

I can't seem to find the appropriate vendor to trade this into. Who has the pieces for these tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the same page you linked, check out the "Currency For" tab. It shows that you can use the mark to buy all sorts of items for the different classes. Click on one of those items and look at the "Sold By" tab. You can see that, for example, you can buy Sanctified Shadowblade Breastplate (rogue t10 chest) from Rafael Langrom in Dalaran or at the Rogue armor vendor in Icecrown Citadel.

If you are looking for a generic answer, all of the armor type (Cloth, Leather, Mail, Plate) vendors in their respective shops in Dalaran will sell items for these marks, as well as the class-specific vendors in ICC.